# How to design a good platform abstraction layer?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

We have central classes and functions in our big project to abstract from the actual platform types, e.g. mutex, file, thread etc. instead of having "fopen" everywhere in the code. While this is good, I would like to go even further and don't have any system includes in the header files (like `#include <windows.h>`), which would be true platform abstraction and faster compilation. On the downside you cannot just typedef to a system type (e.g. Windows HANDLE).

### Option 1: PImpl-idiom

```
class RwMutex
{
    // .....
private:
   struct Impl;
   Impl*   m_Impl;
}
```

- Pro: Implementation and platform types well hidden in Cpp.
- Con: Involves 2-stage construction (the 'new', we don't have exception) which can fail. Laborious to do.

### Option 2: Namespace functions

```
class RwMutex {
public:
    bool LockRead() {return RwMutexLockRead( this );}
private:
    char m_AnonymousMember[ 16 ];
}
bool RwMutexLockRead( RwMutex* p );
```

- Pro: The implementation can be just linked to it, ideal for placing it into a library on its own.
- Con: Involves reinterpret_cast of the space which holds the member. Not nice in the debugger. Also a lot of work.

Maybe I'm to eager on it, but it would be cool if the huge amount of project code would be clean of any platform-dependent includes, maybe enforced by the `-nostdinc` option.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Synchronization stuff, Threads, Filesystem etc. can all be done with boost in a platform independent way.

Comment: It might seem like you could do without std or boost on Windows, but there's no reason to not use them when your requirements practically state so. Huge amounts of time will be saved.

Comment: As I said: I try to hide away system include files. I agree that a lot of time would be saved using Boost, but afaik Boost uses exception, and our code not. Unfortunately, I think it was a wrong decision and we are not using C++ as supposed to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1 using pointers is a bad idea. Use either `boost::scoped_ptr` or, if you can, [`std::unique_ptr`](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/).

Option 2, as you implement it, should not be used. See [GotW #28: The Fast Pimpl Idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm). In C++11 however, this can be done correctly using `std::aligned_storage<>`. I once wrote a `pimpl_ptr<T, Size, Align=default>` that does the casting, copying, destructor call for you and checks that you have chosen the right `Size`.

In general, use pimpl unless you have profiled and shown that this is the bottleneck.

But as always, don't reinvent the wheel.  Mutex and Threads are part of the new C++11 standard, so either upgrade the compiler or use Boost instead. For files use Boost.  The reasoning is, that many parts of the new C++11 library are taken from Boost.

Comment: About option 1: Sure, we have our own UniquePtr<>.

About option 2: Thanks for the link. Sorry for not having a more complete example. We do have an elaborated `AnonymousMember<>` template taking care about alignment and cast, but yes, it's kind of weird.

I guess to "not reinvent the wheel" is the best hint. Unfortunately it will not an option for a long time to require C++11 :-(. Probably I'm over-thinking the problem.

Comment: May I ask you what the `pimpl_ptr` does? If you use a Pimpl idiom, there is no need to take the size for a char-array, as you can new the class from the cpp, knowing the right type and size. If you have a char-array as member like I had it's not really a pimpl anymore.

Comment: @Borph: My `pimpl_ptr` is a wrapper around `std::aligned_storage<>`, but it "feels" like a smart pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Why even have an Implementation object? Your code will not just change on the same platform, you'll be using the same implementation on the platform that your currently using at the time. Define the interface in the header, and provide various *.cpp files for the implementation for each platform you are targeting for. Using #ifndef, #else, etc.

e.g.
Your file system may look like this:

```
include/
    RwMutex.hpp
    // etc...
src/
    RwMutex/
       RwMutexWin32.cpp
       RwMutexUnix.cpp
       // etc...
```

Here's what RwMutexWin32.cpp may look like:

```
#ifdef MYLIBPREFIX_PLATFORM_WIN32
#include "RwMutex.hpp"

#include <Windows.h>

// implement the Windows version of the RwMutex class
```

Another example may be to look at SDL, or some other cross-platform library written in C or C++. They mainly use the preprocessor system. It's not likely you'd want to change what the Impl object points to (i.e. a Unix implementation on a Windows machine wouldn't make sense, nor would it compile).

And of course, if you really want to do this, I'd recommend using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). But as other people have suggested, you should try to use other libraries, such as [boost](http://www.boost.org/) or the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/), it's already written for you.

Comment: Actually we are using CMake and often the `RwMutexWin32.cpp/RwMutexUnix.cpp` way you pointed out, but we place an if/else additionally in the CMakeLists.txt, which I don't really like.
Your class in RwMutex.hpp would not be able to have the Windows `CRITICAL_SECTION` as a member, because it would need the `#include` in the header then.

Comment: The Pimpl-idiom didn't have any purpose of being polymorphic in any kind, just to hide platform types away in the cpp.